# Targeting a class by jumping over divs?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In this html:

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="container1">
        <div class="div_1">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <div class="div_2">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to target the `div_2` like this

```
.main .container1 .container2 .div_2 {}
```

That means the target also has to go through the `container1` div to apply the css.

Why? This could be a very useful trick without using any scripts 
for example targeting `div_2` on a page when `container1` exists while on another page does not exist so it does not work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the adjacent sibling selector (`+`):

```css
.main .container1 + .container2 .div_2 { 
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="div_1">div_1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="div_2">div_2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The selector above is saying: *Target `.div_2`, that is a descendant of `.container2`, which immediately follows its sibling `.container1`, which is a descendant of `.main`*.

References:

- [8.3.1 Adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`)
- [8.3.2 General sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`)
- [CSS Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: Thank you so much sir :)

Answer (score 1):

.main .container1 .container2 .div_2 {} This will only target .div_2 if both .container2 is nested in .container1.

The closest you can get is a sibling selector.

.container1 ~ .container2 .div_2

Comment: The only issue with the adjacent sibling selector is that it will only apply if it is the very next element.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ^^